# libgdx: мерцает экран в режиме DesktopLauncher

Tags: java, android, libgdx

такая проблема, на эмуляторе такого бага не выявлено, если запускаю на пк т.е DesktopLauncher происходит мерцание экрана , на физическом устройстве также мерцает экран.
Класс стартер:

```
public class Drop extends Game {
Camera cam;
Game game;
SpriteBatch batch;
int tempGameScore = 0;//пеерменная для вывода на экране score
int dropsGatchered = 0;
Preferences preferences;//сохраняем игру

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
 this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));



}

@Override
public void render() {

    super.render();


}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    batch.dispose();

}
```

}

Меню:

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen, ApplicationListener {

Sprite texture;
final Drop game;

Skin skin;
Stage stage;
OrthographicCamera camera;

ImageButton newGameButton, exit, highScore;
Table table;
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle btnplayStyle, btnscoreStyle, btnexitStyle;
// Sprite sprite;
//SpriteBatch batch;
private static TextureAtlas atlas, backAtlas;

// Sprite sprite;
//SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create() {


}

public MainMenuScreen(final Drop gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/texture.pack"), true);
    backAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/background.pack"), true);
    texture = new Sprite(backAtlas.findRegion("background"));
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    table = new Table();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.addActor(table);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);// Make the stage consume events

}

@Override
public void show() {
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    btnplayStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    btnplayStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("play");//кнопка не нажата
    btnplayStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("play");
    btnplayStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("play"); // кнопка нажата
    newGameButton = new ImageButton(btnplayStyle);
    newGameButton.setSize(300, 200);

    stage.addActor(newGameButton);
    newGameButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }
    });

    //Button score
    btnscoreStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    btnscoreStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("records");//кнопка не нажата
    btnscoreStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("records");
    btnscoreStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("records"); // кнопка нажата
    highScore = new ImageButton(btnscoreStyle);
    highScore.setSize(300, 200);

    stage.addActor(highScore);
    highScore.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            game.setScreen(new Score(game) {

            });

        }
    });

    //Button EXIT
    btnexitStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    btnexitStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("exit");//кнопка не нажата
    btnexitStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("exit");
    btnexitStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("exit"); // кнопка нажата
    exit = new ImageButton(btnexitStyle);
    exit.setSize(300, 200);

    stage.addActor(exit);
    exit.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    });
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(texture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    game.batch.end();

    table.add(newGameButton).width(400).height(100);
    table.getCell(newGameButton).spaceBottom(30);
    table.row();

    table.add(highScore).width(400).height(100);

    table.getCell(highScore).spaceBottom(30);
    table.row();

    table.add(exit).width(400).height(100);
    table.getCell(exit).spaceBottom(30);
    table.row();

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void render() {

    System.out.println("ичего ен рисуем");
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё таки лучше хоть что-то да выводить
например:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

Иначе мусор может выводиться на реальных устройствах